# Run a method before starting spring kafka-consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Can anyone please suggest how run a method for initializing my app before spring starts its kafka-consumer?
I am using @KafkaListener annotation of spring to create a kafka consumer

Comment: what are u looking exactly ? there are multiple ways of doing it ? it will be good if u can say what exactly u are looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, give us more info what type of initialization you are looking for. The `@KafkaListener` can be marked with `autoStartup="false"`. So, you are free to do whatever you need and then you call `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` for starting respective container manually: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle

Comment: In my app I want to fetch some data from the db, before I start listening to kafka. And the above doc you pasted, just helps in doing the same.
Thanks!